# Android keystore cannot resolve key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

i was generating update for my app but got this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key brainstudio_talkingbattery from store "C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\brainstudio_talkingBattery.jks": Cannot recover key

i read almost all the related issues but did'nt find any solution.

I am sure my keystore password is correct as i got detail of key from this command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore brainstudio_talkingBattery.jks
```

plus my keystore password and key password are same

i am totally stuck into it, please help

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Sorry did find the solution yet :(

Comment: I did find the solution. I was sure my key and password was correct. but after a lot of tries, i found out that i had a different password. So even if you think you are putting the right password, just change the case or try some other passwords that you use